# Static page lazy loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to do page load when scrolling down. When I started searching for code I found stuff only for dynamic pages. I did not get any code for static pages.

Please help me. How to do when scrolling down at certain points in a static page, not dynamic page. My code structure is below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <article class="blog_post">
        <h4><a href="" target="_blank"><b>Self-driving Trucks Face Regulatory, Technical Hurdles</b></a></h4>
        <div class="blog_category" style="font-size:14px">
          <ul>
            <li>Fresh releases</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="blog_text" style="font-size:14px">
          <ul>
            <li>| </li>
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Post By : Trucks.com</a></li>
            <li>| </li>
            <li>On : 12 Dec 2016</li>
            <li>| </li>
            <li>
              <span class="fb-share-button" data-href="" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true">
                <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup()"><img id="my-img" style="width:2%;" class="social" src="images/br4Br.png" /></a>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li>| </li>
            <li><a data-site="" class="ssba_twitter_share" onclick="popup('')" target="_blank"><img id="my-img" class="social2" src="images/t1.png" /></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="blog_post_img">
          <a href="" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/blog_post_img73.jpg" alt="image">
            <span style="font-size:10px;">Torbjörn Holmström, senior advisor to Volvo's Research & Technology Group. (Photo: Volvo)</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <p>For several decades now, Torbjörn Holmström has been helping Volvo vault the technical and logistical barriers to fulfill the dream of fully autonomous long-haul trucks.</p>
        <a href="" target="_blank">Continue reading <i class="fa  element" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </article>
      <article class="blog_post">
        <h4><a href="" target="_blank"><b>Nikola Motors Wants to Use Tech to Fix Trucking's Millennial Problem</b></a></h4>
        <div class="blog_category">
          <ul>
            <li>Fresh releases</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="blog_text">
            <ul>
              <li>| </li>
              <li><a href="" target="_blank">Post By : Inverse</a></li>
              <li>| </li>
              <li>On : 11 Dec 2016</li>
              <li>| </li>
              <li>
                <span class="fb-share-button" data-href="" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true">
                  <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="popup('')"><img id="my-img" style="width:2%;" class="social" src="images/f1.png" /></a>
                </span>
              </li>
              <li>| </li>
              <li><a data-site="" class="ssba_twitter_share" onclick="popup('')" target="_blank"><img id="my-img" class="social2" src="images/t1.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="blog_post_img">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
              <img src="images/blog_post_img72.png" alt="image">
            </a>
          </div>
          <p>Nikola Motor Company has <a href="" target="_blank">gotten a lot of attention</a> for its <a href="" target="_blank">hydrogen-powered trucks</a>. And it should: Hydrogen fuel cells make the trucks environmentally friendly, more powerful than diesel-reliant vehicles, and safer than their predecessors.</p>
          <a href="" target="_blank">Continue reading <i class="fa  element" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </article>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have so many articles and it will update daily around 8 to 10 articles. If I start scrolling down it will take so much time to reach the bottom articles. So Please help me.

Comment: post your javascript

Comment: I did not get any javascript.....

Comment: And how are you planning to do this without Javascript?

Comment: HAHAHA you want to load things in your 'static' page...... Please lookup the meaning of the word static. This by definition makes it dynamic